# How to check if record exists or not and insert in ms access database in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I want to check if record exists or not if it exists i dont want to insert if it bot i want to insert the data in ms access database in c#.

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into MyTable values('" + test + "','" + test + "','" + "123" + "');", con);
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from MyTable", con);
        temp = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string count = (string)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
            temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (temp > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("One Record Added");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record not added");
            }


        }
        catch
        { }
```

Can Anyone suggest me some code.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Questions are the answers. You indeed have the solution.

Comment: i did not understand can u pls say me where i am wrong

Comment: when i am using these duplicates are inserted

Comment: As you are not checking for the record existence . See the answer , hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter your Select query on the basis of some key . Check if it returns for existence or non-existence of the particular record and do the processing required .

```
 string cmdStr = "Select count(*) from MyTable where id = 1"; //get the existence of the record as count 

 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr, conn);

  int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

  if(count >0)
  {
         //record already exist 
  }
```

Modify this line

```
  OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from MyTable", con);
```