# How to check that any particular record already exist in the database or not before inserting record in MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code to export data from excel to Sql server database. What is going on with this code is, its importing complete data into the database.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Importexcel()
    {            
        if (Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
            string path1 = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFolder"), Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path1))
                System.IO.File.Delete(path1);
            Request.Files["FileUpload1"].SaveAs(path1);
            string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=xyz-101\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PracDB;Trusted_Connection=true;Persist Security Info=True";
            string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[Name],[Designation] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
            excelConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dReader;               
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Excel_Table";
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            excelConnection.Close();
        }  
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

How to check that any particular record already exist in the database or not. If not then Insert the record into the databse else it should not.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8047034/1298308

Answer (score 0):

Since your target is SQL Server, you can use this to your advantage.
What I would do is read the data from the excel into a DataTable (instead of using a DataReader you can use a DataAdapter), Send that DataTable to a stored procedure in the SQL server, and handle the insert there. In order to sand a data table to a stored procedure you first need to create a Table-value user defined type in your sql server, like this:

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE 
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(20), -- use whatever length best fitted to your data
    Designation varchar(max) -- use whatever length best fitted to your data
)
```

Then you can write a simple stored procedure with an argument of this type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDataFromExcel
( 
    @ExcelData dbo.MyType readonly -- Note: readonly is a required!
)
AS

INSERT INTO MyTable(Id, Name, Designation)
SELECT a.Id, a.Name, a.Designation
FROM @ExcelData a LEFT JOIN 
MyTable b ON(a.Id = b.Id)
WHERE b.Id IS NULL -- this condition with the left join ensures you only select records that has different id values then the records already in your database
```

in order to send this parameter to the stored procedure from your c# code you will have to use a `SqlCommand` object and add the DataTable as a parameter, something like this:

```
using(SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)) 
{
    using(SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("InsertDataFromExcel", Con))
    { 
        SqlParameter MyParam = new SqlParameter("@ExcelData", SqlDBType.Structured);
        MyParam.Value = MyDataTable; // this is the data table from the 
        InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(MyParam);
        Con.Open();
        InsertCommand.ExecuteNoQuery();
        Con.Close();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Code was writen directly here, some errors might be found.