# Check for the existence of a record in Access database using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, exception, try-catch, nullreferenceexception

First, I did search for this first and found this question answered: [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046955/how-to-check-if-record-exists-or-not-and-insert-in-ms-access-database-in-c-sharp)

The problem I have with this answer is that using this method causes a `NullReferenceException`.  Obviously the code will still work with a try/catch block, but I had always understood that intentionally using an Exception as a means of controlling flow was poor design.  Is there a better method of doing this?

To be clear as to the parameters, I am using OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand to read/write an Access 2010 database (.accdb format).

Below is the code I have currently using the above answer's approach:

```
public bool ReadAccessDb(string filePath, string queryString, bool hasRecords)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=" + filePath + ";" +
            @"User Id=;Password=;";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                int count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                //This works, but if no records exist it uses the Exception system to halt further action.  Look for better approach.
                if(count > 0)
                {
                    hasRecords = true;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        return hasRecords;
    }
```

Comment: So are you passing a SELECT query to your method? If so, you could wrap it in a `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM ( <YourSelectQuery> )` and see if that returns zero.

Comment: I marked the other as it's an actual answer (which thus allows me to), but I do like the idea of using a SELECT statement instead.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
int count = command.ExecuteScalar() is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

or use :

```
object obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
int count = obj is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(obj);
```

Comment: The first answer gave threw exception ObjectNotSetToInstance, but the 2nd answer worked perfectly.  I'm not usually a fan of using the object variable type (I'm probably wrong, but it just usually seems imprecise, like using the var type), but if it works I'm good with it.  Thanks!

Comment: Try to do this : `int count = command.ExecuteScalar() is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());`

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer because the question is a bit ambiguous and the (currently) accepted answer can conceivably be "fooled" if a row exists but the first column returned by the SELECT statement happens to contain a NULL. Consider the test table

`CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, NullableColumn INTEGER NULL)`

`INSERT INTO MyTable (NullableColumn) VALUES (NULL)`

which would look like

```
ID  NullableColumn
--  --------------
 1          <NULL>
```

If the SELECT statement used for testing was

```cs
string sql = "SELECT NullableColumn FROM MyTable WHERE ID=1";
```

then the method

```cs
static bool RecordExists(string queryString, OleDbConnection conn)
{
    bool rtn;
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn))
    {
        object obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
        int count = obj is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(obj);
        rtn = (count != 0);
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

would return `False`, whereas this method

```cs
static bool RecordExists(string queryString, OleDbConnection conn)
{
    bool rtn;
    string rowCountString = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM ({0})", queryString);
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(rowCountString, conn))
    {
        int count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        rtn = (count != 0);

    }
    return rtn;
}
```

would return `True`.